# Jupyter: can't create new notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have some existing Python code that I want to convert to a Jupyter notebook. I have run:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Now I can see this in my browser:

[image]

But how do I create a new notebook? The `Notebook` link in the menu is greyed out, and I can't see any other options to create a new notebook.

I've noticed this on the command line while Jupyter is running:

```
[W 22:30:08.128 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) is not available
```

Comment: How did you install Jupyter? Do you have the IPython kernel installed?

Comment: Ah, I installed it with `pip` and manually uninstalled `ipython` because I already had iPython and I thought thought Jupyter superseded iPython. Redoing `pip install ipython` solved the problem, thanks! Please submit as an answer!

Comment: No problem - I'll add an answer below...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you don't have an IPython kernel installed (or any other kernel for that matter!).

There are various ways ([old versions](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html), [new versions](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html)) to do this. One of the simplest ways is to use pip. From the command line enter:

```
pip install ipython
```

You may also need to register the kernel with Jupyter (see the [new versions](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html) page):

```
python -m pip install ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install [--user] [--name <machine-readable-name>] [--display-name <"User Friendly Name">]
```

You should now be able to launch a Python notebook from Jupyter.

Alternatively, installing Jupyter using any of the methods on [this page](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#how-to-install-jupyter-notebook) should ensure that the IPython kernel is already there. Personally, Anaconda has always just worked out of the box for me (when I've used it on Linux and Mac OS).

Comment: I had the same problem (and same command line message). It was not fixed when I tried reinstalling ipython. However, I noticed that when I tried to run "ipython" I got an
ImportError: No module named path.
A little Googling revealed this link
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/525
which suggests trying
pip install path.py
And this worked for me (i.e. I can now make Python notebooks)!

Comment: Thank you Gregory, that did it for me. It's irritating that this isn't better documented!

Comment: Thank you so much! `python -m pip install ipykernel` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 17):

None of the other answers worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. After 2 days of struggling, I finally realized that I needed to install the latest version of IPython (not the one in pip). First, I uninstalled ipython from my system with:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ipython
sudo pip uninstall ipython
```

I don't know if you need both, but both did something on my system.

Then, I installed ipython from source like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
cd ipython
sudo pip install -e .
```

Note the period at the end of the last line. After this, I reran jupyter notebook and the python2 kernel was detected!

Comment: I had a similar problem.  For me, it was enough to do `pip install ipython --upgrade`.  That took me from ipython 3.2.1 to ipython 4.1.2.  (The older version was there because I installed a package named `bayesdb` and all its dependencies.)  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove ipython      works for me on UBUNTU 16.04

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue but looks like this its because I was using **python 2.7**. I was able to launch notebook by clicking on **"Python 2"** dropdown option.

Answer (score 3):

For me the error was:

> ERROR: notebook 6.0.0 has requirement tornado>=5.0, but you'll have tornado 4.5.3 which is incompatible.

I solved it by following the below steps:

```
pip uninstall ipykernel
pip install --upgrade tornado
pip install ipykernel
```

Now open jupyter notebook from terminal. It should work fine.

Comment: This solved my issue, on MacOS 10.14.5 with a built-from-source installation of Python 3.6.4. I got the same error notice after running `pip install jupyterlab` followed these steps, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it is because I installed ipython with `sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook` instead of `sudo pip install ipython`.
Therefore, uninstall all ipython stuff using:
`sudo apt-get --purge remove ipython
sudo pip uninstall ipython`

and then install it with pip

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. My error snapshot is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039349/no-python-terminal-in-jupyter-notebook). Following below solved my problem:

1. `sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook`
2. `sudo -H pip install jupyter`

It was not working because I was getting `0` active kernel message and this came because I installed jupyter using step2 only (skipped step1).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, for me it was solved by running

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Answer (score 0):

because ipython version is too new.
you can use follow commands

```
pip uninstall ipython
pip install ipython==5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if you have cookies enabled in your browser. Without cookies, the listing of the directory appears empty, as does the notebook creation menu.