# custom-written `python setup.py install` conflicts with jupyter notebook python kernel

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I can install jupyter and have it run python 2.7 notebooks with no problem using `pip` on Ubuntu 14.04. However, as soon as I try to build my own custom-written modules with `python setup.py install`, I can no longer start a notebook and get the following error telling me the Native kernel (python2) is not available and that ipywidgets is not installed:

```
[W 15:14:06.033 NotebookApp] ipywidgets package not installed.  Widgets are unavailable.
[I 15:14:06.040 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
[I 15:14:06.040 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 15:14:06.040 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:8888/
[I 15:14:06.040 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 15:14:19.357 NotebookApp] Uploading file to /Untitled.ipynb
[I 15:14:19.361 NotebookApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /home/qsi/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
[W 15:14:54.628 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) is not available
```

I have no clue how to fix it. I've tried to install the kernel manually as well as [installing ipython again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851801/jupyter-cant-create-new-notebook), but nothing helps. I'm guessing the `setup.py` somehow causes conflicts. Below is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='test_module',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='',
    packages = find_packages(),
    package_data = {
    },
    url='',
    license='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    install_requires=[
        'numpy>=1.0'
    ]
)
```

Comment: setuptools may have screwed something up - it's liable to do that if you run `setup.py install`, so it's now always recommended to do `pip install .` instead. Try looking for `.pth` files, or use [damnpth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/damnpth), a tool I wrote to find them automatically.

Comment: `pip install .` did it for me. can you add it as an answer?...thanks!