# How to launch IPython kernel in Jupyter?

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have both `Jupyter` and `IPython` installed on my Mac OSX El Capitan.

But, for some reason when I launch `Jupyter`, I'm not able to start any `ipython` kernels in notebook.

I think that `ipython` is installed because I can see it when I do `which ipython`: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ipython`

And, when I do `which jupyter` I see the following:  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/jupyter`

When I launch `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, I'm able to open the `ipynb` file, but then I see this at the top:

[IPython kernel "None not found"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3hic.png) (I can't embed images without sufficient reputation, so please click it).

...which is kind of strange because:

- 1) it's a double negative
- 2) I already have IPython installed, so I don't know why it can't start the kernel (that's what this question says to try: [Jupyter: can't create new notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851801/jupyter-cant-create-new-notebook))

Also, when I click the `New` button at the top, it does not show "notebook" under the options.  It only shows "Text File", "Folder", "Terminal":

["New" dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWdr6.png)

Comment: Is the `ipykernel` package installed? And if you open the 'New' dropdown menu from the notebook dashboard, what options does it list under Notebook?

Comment: Have you installed IPython for the Python interpreter which runs the Jupyter notebook?  What does `which jupyter` say?

Comment: @ThomasK, I just installed it, but I must say this is strange:  I installed `ipykernel` like this: `sudo python -m pip install -U ipykernel`, but then now when I do `which jupyter` nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had different versions of python associated with `Jupyter` and `IPython`.  To solve this, I did:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install jupyter
sudo python3 -m pip install ipython
```