# jupyter notebook not showing python option under new

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, temp

I am having a problem with creating a new ipython notebook.
Previously I used to do that going to new -> python
but now I am unable to see any python option.
Also, I am unable to open any ipython notebooks, I have one uploading for hours now.

I recently erased my %temp% folder to free some space in the C drive. Does that have something to do with this? How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: what's your output of jupyter --version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter: can't create new notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851801/jupyter-cant-create-new-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!
For some reason, jupyter labs was not installed
So running  the command

```
jupyter -- version
```

and then checking what all was installed, I found out that jupyter labs was not installed?

```
pip3 install jupyter labs
```

so I went ahead and installed it and everything works as it did before.
Still don't know the reason why this all happened in particular. If anyone could help me with  that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100% but this is most commonly related to an ipython jupyter notebook file error. I do recommend to do a clean install of the notebook and try again. As I don't have any specifications on your system is difficult to guide you on the process. But that is the best option you have now.

Also this could have happened because of an update on python, jupyter, your system or any base component required by jupyter or python.